# Error while running shortcut of EXE on user's machine

Tags: vb.net, exe, execution

I have made an application using VB.NET which is used inhouse.
In order to avoid everytime changing of exe on user's (multiple user) machine
I want to use shortcut of exe on user's machine.

Where EXE is placed in one central location(Server).

**I am getting bellow error on user's machine :**

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcPermission, System.Data, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

**Error after clicking on ok button:**

```
Application attempted to perform not allowed by the security policy.Togrant this application the required permission,contact your system administrator,or use the Microsoft .NET Framework Configuration tool.
```

**Details of Error :**

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Focus()
   at Reports.UserLoginForm.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
The action that failed was:
Demand
The type of the first permission that failed was:
System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission
The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
Internet


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Reports
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file://10.80.100.32/softwares/S0Bom_TCN-05-05-2011/Debug/Reports.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.1433 (REDBITS.050727-1400)
```

Comment: thilink may help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179521(sql.80).aspx

Comment: Not a solution to your exact problem but have you thought about [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) deployment - this is suited exactly to your scenario and gets you away from installation headaches.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  Everything on a remote system (file share) is less trusted than if it were local.  You will have to change the CAS policy settings to allow this remove executable specific permissions (or all permissions).  You can do this with the [caspol.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) file that comes with your specific version of .NET. [Link on how to do that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx).